# Python need better solution for declaring and initializing 50+ global variables

Tags: python, global

I have been designing a framework and I have a config.py where I initialize numerous db (global) variables from a config.ini file. The python's ways of declaring global variable seems quite untidy.
See the example below:

```
    import configparser as cp

    # Initializing the global variables
    def config_init():
    global env, test_env, oracle_conn_str, # similarly n number of variables

    # Reading connection_config.ini
    conn_config_dir = common.file_path('../reusables/connection_config.ini')
    conn_config = cp.ConfigParser()
    conn_config.read(conn_config_dir)
    env = conn_config['Constants']['env']
    test_env = conn_config[env]
    oracle_conn_str = test_env['oracle_conn_str']
```

The problem here is I have to initialize all the global variables in the outer scope with null value before the function definitions else I get pycharm warning like

```
Global variable <var_name> is undefined at the module level
```

To avoid the warning I have to initialize all the global variables in the outer scope like

```
src_config = dt_config = env = test_env = ''
```

The code looks quite untidy when we have 100+ global variables. Any solution please for a conventional way rather warning override

Comment: just put all your config in a single dict or object.

Comment: And if you want something more robust, Pydantic w/dotenv helps you with handling configurations with environment and `.env` support + validation of settings: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/settings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `global` keyword, I recommend you place your global variables inside a globals class.

Example:

```py
class GLOBAL:
    a: int = 5
    b: int = 10
    # n variables

def main():
   GLOBAL.a = 10
   print(GLOBAL.a)


main()
```

Comment: Hi, please help me in the following scenario:
I have **config.py** which has a global dict  **config.dict**  and one of the keys contain list of table_names from the db. I have to then unpack the list items and assign to different global variables. (say if the list contains 20 table names I have to assign them to 20 variables) and use it globally

Comment: @rams Why do you need twenty separate variables? Why not a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You actually dont have to initialize them, I try never to use Global variables.
One way you can do it is by creating a list in the main boy and the use it.
You change the list inside functions and so on and ou can store any type of varible inside a list.